# column does not exist OR schema does not exist error in AWS Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

A working query needs changing to include a colunm from another table. Upon LEFT JOINing I get a 'column does not exist' error. Using the column instead of the column alias in the ON statement the first error turns into a 'schema does not exist' error.

This yields the 'column "a.audience_id" does not exist error'

```
        select
            criteria,
            trim(split_part(criteria, ':', 3))  as audience_id,
            t.category as audience_name,
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY trim(split_part(criteria, ':', 3)) ORDER BY date desc) as rownumber
        from
            client.adwords_insights_audience a
            left join core.googleads_inmarketaudience_xref x
            on a.audience_id = x.criterion_id
        group by
        criteria,
           trim(split_part(criteria, ':', 3)),
            t.category
```

And a change in the ON clause to the below yields the 'schema "a" does not exist' error

```
        select
            criteria,
            trim(split_part(criteria, ':', 3))  as audience_id,
            t.category as audience_name,
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY trim(split_part(criteria, ':', 3)) ORDER BY date desc) as rownumber
        from
            client.adwords_insights_audience a
            left join core.googleads_inmarketaudience_xref x
            on a.trim(split_part(criteria, ':', 3)) = x.criterion_id
        group by
        criteria,
           trim(split_part(criteria, ':', 3)),
            t.category
```

The original query (below) works perfectly. It's only when I LEFT JOIN that the errors arise.

```
        select
            criteria,
            trim(split_part(criteria, ':', 3))  as audience_id,
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY trim(split_part(criteria, ':', 3)) ORDER BY date desc) as rownumber
        from
            client.adwords_insights_audience a
        group by
        criteria,
           trim(split_part(criteria, ':', 3))
```

The 'date' column is ok as well, I removed it from this post along with several others for clarity. I'm hoping for the t.category column in the final output.

Comment: My conclusion is that `client.adwords_insights_audience` does not have a column called `audience_it`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that if you fix the table aliases, your query might work.  The following is my best guess on where the columns come from:

```
select x.criteria,
       trim(split_part(x.criteria, ':', 3))  as audience_id,
       a.category as audience_name,
       row_number() over (partition by trim(split_part(x.criteria, ':', 3)) order by  ?.date desc) as rownumber
from client.adwords_insights_audience a left join 
     core.googleads_inmarketaudience_xref x
     on a.audience_id = x.criterion_id
group by x.criteria,
         trim(split_part(x.criteria, ':', 3)),
         a.category;
```

The `?` is because I have no idea where `date` comes from.

Comment: I removed many column names that aren't causing the problem for clarity in this post. 'date' is a valid column.

Comment: @Alex . . . Of course `date` is a valid column.  You should qualify *all* column references, particularly when referencing more than one table.  Something seems amiss with the column references.